# Calculate the sum on the 24 hours time frame in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to calculate the sum on date and date+1(24 hours) by filtering the rows based on hours.

```
1, 2018-05-01 02:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-01 03:16:10,2
1, 2018-05-01 09:12:00,4
1, 2018-05-01 14:18:00,3
1, 2018-05-01 18:32:00,1
1, 2018-05-01 20:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 01:22:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 02:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 08:30:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 10:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 11:32:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 18:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-03 03:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-03 08:22:00,1
```

Here, example I have filtered the rows from 9AM to 9AM(next date)
Output

```
1, 2018-05-01,12
1, 2018-05-02,5
```

Comment: What should result look like?

Comment: @ipj Here the sum should calculate for 24 hours period. sum should be between 09:00:00 to next data 09:00:00 (next date). Example for 2018-05-01, sum is 12

Comment: @swati,  If the answer helped you to resolve issue.. Could you **`upvote and accept`** the answer to close this thread! :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just shift the time of your timestamp column by 9 hours and then groupby the date of the adjusted column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, sum as fsum 

df
# DataFrame[id: int, dtime: timestamp, cnt: int]

df.groupby("id", expr("date(dtime - interval 9 hours) as ddate")) \
  .agg(fsum("cnt").alias("cnt")) \
  .show()
+---+----------+---+
| id|     ddate|cnt|
+---+----------+---+
|  1|2018-05-01| 12|
|  1|2018-05-02|  5|
|  1|2018-04-30|  3|
+---+----------+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

First define `df` for reproducibility:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
data=\
"""
1, 2018-05-01 02:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-01 03:16:10,2
1, 2018-05-01 09:12:00,4
1, 2018-05-01 14:18:00,3
1, 2018-05-01 18:32:00,1
1, 2018-05-01 20:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 01:22:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 02:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 08:30:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 10:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 11:32:00,1
1, 2018-05-02 18:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-03 03:12:00,1
1, 2018-05-03 08:22:00,1
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep = ',', names = ['id','t', 'n'], parse_dates =['t'])
```

Then use `pd.Grouper` with frequency set to 24h and `base` parameter set to 9, which indicates period is beggining at 9 a.m.:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='t', freq='24h', base=9)).n.sum()
```

result:

```
t
2018-04-30 09:00:00     3
2018-05-01 09:00:00    12
2018-05-02 09:00:00     5
Freq: 24H, Name: n, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks @ipj, do you know how to implement in pyspark or spark-scala

Answer (score 0):

Use **`date_format(), date_add(),to_date()`** and then **`groupBy,aggregate`** spark built in functions.

**`Example:`**

**`Spark-Scala:`**

```
df.show()
//+---+-------------------+---+
//| id|               date|cnt|
//+---+-------------------+---+
//|  1|2018-05-01 02:12:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-01 03:16:10|  2|
//|  1|2018-05-01 09:12:00|  4|
//|  1|2018-05-01 14:18:00|  3|
//|  1|2018-05-01 18:32:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-01 20:12:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-02 01:22:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-02 02:12:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-02 08:30:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-02 10:12:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-02 11:32:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-02 18:12:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-03 03:12:00|  1|
//|  1|2018-05-03 08:22:00|  1|
//+---+-------------------+---+

df.withColumn("hour",when(date_format(col("date"),"HH").cast("int") >= 9,to_date(col("date"))).otherwise(date_add(to_date(col("date")),-1))).
groupBy("id","hour").
agg(sum("cnt").cast("int").alias("sum")).
show()
//+---+----------+---+
//| id|      hour|sum|
//+---+----------+---+
//|  1|2018-05-01| 12|
//|  1|2018-05-02|  5|
//|  1|2018-04-30|  3|
//+---+----------+---+
```

**`Pyspark:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df.withColumn("hour",when(date_format(col("date"),"HH").cast("int") >= 9,to_date(col("date"))).otherwise(date_add(to_date(col("date")),-1))).\
groupBy("id","hour").\
agg(sum("cnt").cast("int").alias("sum")).\
show()
#+---+----------+---+
#| id|      hour|sum|
#+---+----------+---+
#|  1|2018-05-01| 12|
#|  1|2018-05-02|  5|
#|  1|2018-04-30|  3|
#+---+----------+---+
```

Comment: @swati,  If the answer helped you to resolve issue.. Could you **`upvote and accept`** the answer to close this thread! :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work